# Get Artwork of current iTunes track

Tags: objective-c, itunes, scripting-bridge, artwork

I searched all over the web and this site to understand how to get the artwork of the current iTunes track. any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate iTunes.h using the following command:

```sh
sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes
```

You can then use `iTunes` to get the current playing track:

```
#import "iTunes.h"

iTunesApplication *app = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
iTunesTrack *currentTrack = app.currentTrack;
```

Then get the album artwork for the current track:

```
SBElementArray *artworks = [currentTrack artworks];
iTunesArtwork *artwork = artworks[0];
```

Comment: That's weird. Here is a copy I found on github: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-iTunes/blob/master/src/iTunes.h

Comment: I found the solution. I need to use `xcrun sdef in Mountain Lion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I' ve another problem. the terminal command creates the "iTunes.h" file and then I' ve imported it in my project but after that I can't compile with success. The error is:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SBApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PanelController.o

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333551/weird-error-with-apple-script-bridge-itunes will help

Comment: Yes! sorry about that! Thanks!